# Smallest distance between two words (python)

Tags: python, full-text-search

Here are two versions I could think of. V2 is preferable when both words are common (say "is" and "the", for which the n1*n2 scaling of version 1 would be a problem), and more robust to malicious input (say a file with  only two words). But for more interesting queries (say "big" and "animal") v1 is as fast and I can think of more realistic semantic problems for which v2 wouldn't work at all but v1 would. Is there a way to speed it up?

import timeit
t1=timeit.default_timer()

def distance(version, filename, wordOne, wordTwo):

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
text = f.read()
f.close()
index = 0
distance = index
version = int(version)
print 'inputs', filename, wordOne, wordTwo
countOne = 0
countTwo = 0

print 'version', version

if version == 1:
    word_pos = {}
    for word in text.split():
        if word in [wordOne, wordTwo]:
            if word in word_pos.keys():
                word_pos[word].append(index)
            else:
                word_pos[word] = [index]

        index += 1

    countOne = len(word_pos[wordOne])
    countTwo = len(word_pos[wordTwo])

    distances = []
    low = 0
    high = index
    for posOne in word_pos[wordOne]:
        for posTwo in word_pos[wordTwo]:
            #shrink innner loop by distance?:
            #for posTwo in range(int(posOne-distance), (posOne+distance)):
            #if abs(posOne-posTwo) < distance:
            #distance = abs(posOne-posTwo)
            distances.append(abs(posOne-posTwo))
    distance = min(distances)

elif version == 2:
    switch = 0
    indexOne = 0
    indexTwo = 0
    distance = len(text)
    for word in text.split():

        if word == wordOne:
            indexOne = index
            countOne += 1
        if word == wordTwo:
            indexTwo = index
            countTwo += 1

        if indexOne != 0 and indexTwo != 0:
            if distance > abs(indexOne-indexTwo):
                distance = abs(indexOne - indexTwo)

        index += 1

t2 = timeit.default_timer()
print 'Delta t:', t2 - t1

print 'number of words in text:', index
print 'number of occurrences of',wordOne+':', countOne
print 'number of occurrences of',wordTwo+':', countTwo
if countOne < 1 or countTwo < 1:
    print 'not all words are present'
    return 1

print 'Shortest distance between \''+wordOne+'\' and \''+wordTwo+'\' is', distance, 'words'
return distance
```

Comment: Your second version doesn't work, you'll have NameError in `if word == wordOne` . How `wordOne` is initialised?

Comment: Worked for me. wordOne is an input. Did it throw the NameError for you?

Answer (score 1):

The expensive part in v2 is the `if indexOne != 0 ...` block. It's called as many times as there are remaining words in the text once both `wordOne` and `wordTwo` are found. Using the switch variable (I see you had the intention to use it :) it's possible to move that if block into both `if word == wordOne` and `if word == wordTwo`. In that case the block is called less than n1 + n2 times.

Here is the code. Note that we don't longer need to check indexes.

```
elif version == 3:
    last_word_is_one = None
    indexOne = 0
    indexTwo = 0
    countOne = 0
    countTwo = 0
    distance = len(text)
    for word in text.split():

        if word == wordOne:
            indexOne = index
            countOne += 1

            if last_word_is_one == False:
                if distance > abs(indexOne-indexTwo):
                    distance = abs(indexOne - indexTwo)

            last_word_is_one = True

        if word == wordTwo:
            indexTwo = index
            countTwo += 1

            if last_word_is_one == True:
                if distance > abs(indexOne-indexTwo):
                    distance = abs(indexOne - indexTwo)

            last_word_is_one = False

        index += 1
```

Comment: Nice one, and you're right, that's what I had intended to do :-)